# Construct DialogFragment from within static ListFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

I am using **Actionbarsherlock** and have a **ListFragment** and a **DialogFragment** within my Fragment activity.

```
    public class RemainingTasks extends SherlockFragmentActivity{
        public static class CurrentListFragment extends SherlockListFragment{
                 //##need to call addDialog() from within one of the methods here
            }

    public void addDialog() {
          //Create and show the dialog.
          DialogFragment newFragment = MyDialogFragment.newInstance();
          newFragment.show(ft, "dialog");
    }

    public static class MyDialogFragment extends SherlockDialogFragment{

    }
}
```

Now, I need to invoke the `addDialog()` method (which will show a new dialog) from within the static **CurrentListFragment**, but am not able to.

What I tried:

1. When I do a `getActivity()`, I end up with SherlockActivity, and not the FragmentActivity.
2. Unable to call `getSupportFragmentManager()` (Err: Static reference to non-static method)

Is there some way to do this?
Also, is the way I am going about this right, or is there a better way?

Comment: What means "am not able to"? Why?

Comment: @Egor, I added what I tried to the question. From within the static `CurrentListFragment`, I am unable to refer to the `RemainingTasks` class, in order to call `addDialog()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.
Moved the following functions to my MainActivity (which extends SherlockFragmentActivity, and acts as a host for the `RemainingTasks` fragment)

```
public void addDialog() {}
```

and

```
public static class MyDialogFragment extends SherlockDialogFragment{

    }
```

Then I now call it using `((MainActivity)getActivity()).addDialog()`